# Starting aFunction() in Android on app startup

Tags: android

This Android app developing business is accelerating the brown-to-grey-color conversion of my hair.

Can someone tell me how I'm supposed to get `aFunction()` to run when the app starts, seeing as I'm not supposed to make a while(true) inside `onCreate()`?

I've read the tutorial on Android Developer, several other tutorials, multiple questions on here, but none have answered this, seemingly, simple question. Or, at least I haven't been able to find it - without a doubt because I'm asking the wrong question to the great oracle of Amphitheatre Parkway.

The app is my first homemade non-tutorial app, and I'm attempting to make a speedometer based on GPS (obviously). Basic stuff I guess. It needs to update ever so often which I'm using Thread.sleep() for. Setting up `LocationManager`, getting location, calculating distance and speed is working. Printing the speed is working. Everything, except making it run, is working (he claims in his naivety).

Comment: @A--C Doh! Beat me to it.

Comment: Kick off a thread or asynctask? Seems like a better place for anything resembling `while(true)` than the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android development (and in fact most GUI development) is very different than the console development you may have done in the past. The main difference is that GUIs are event-driven. You typically create what are called "callback methods" which respond to events. This allows the system to do other things rather than waiting for a `while(true)` loop in your app. I am unfamiliar with using GPS in an Android app. You will need to research what callbacks are necessary to deal with GPS notifications. I suggest starting with [Making Your App Location Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/index.html) and [Location and Maps](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html).

Comment: If that is truly the only reason for the loop, [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) has `requestLocationUpdates()` which can take in a time interval for regular updates.

Comment: @A--C That was my guess, too, as to the OP's intent. I am unfamiliar with the LocationManager API and unable to give specifics. Thanks for the tip. Hopefully it helps the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I'm coming from console development and embedded systems. I've utilized the code from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ to implement LocationManager; I strongly hope it works.

I will read up on callback methods, thanks.

Comment: @A--C, I will try to look into it. Thanks for your insight. I'm not quite sure if it is all I need; the `while`-loop gets new location as well as calculate the distance and speed, and printing it to screen.

Comment: @Alrekr if you provide a Listener to the method, I think you should be able to skip the loop. Of course, the most important thing is to try something :-)

Comment: @Alrekr With the correct callback function registered (most likely with LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() as A--C suggests), Android will repeatedly notify your app about GPS location without the need for a while loop in your own code.